# Is it possible to have one type's type predicated on the value of another type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have a  component that accepts a `tagType` prop. If that tag type is **Link** or **a**, I need the `link` prop to be required. If the `tagType` is **button** or **input**, then the `link` prop should not be required.

Here's what I have so far, but can't figure out how to set the type of `link` accordingly:

```
type linkTagTypes = 'Link' | 'a'
type nonLinkTagTypes = 'button' | 'input'

type tProps = {
  tagType: linkTagTypes | nonLinkTagTypes,
  link: string,
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possibilities is to use union type, but not for the `tagType` property, but for the `tProps`, like following:

```
type tProps = {
  tagType: linkTagTypes,
  link: string
} | {
  tagType: nonLinkTagTypes,
  link?: string
}
```

Check this one playground for its usage: [Make link required only in one case](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBANglgOwNYBUCGBzF4IGcoC8UA5ADKJLFQA+JaxA3AFCiRQID2C5y6WO+IsQBGAV2DAuVWsURhxjJixxRgABQBOHMIKgBvJlFWZskAFywKfU3gA0hy8gu5gGxBiYBfGvofATOBac3FYBkLj2RvDIAPzOru5eSgDGXC6OSIT6-vzmdMS2GRbEwHjAxJ7MqQjp0UgA6nDAABYAohpaGll6OTbFPJSVTNXpnMAD3b2BJGISUoV1xaUuFVVpwOwc4xSNLRzi7Z2TYRDFcgpDTAAUi6qa2rgAlMw3O01tHRwaFupaOs-XMYDH73f4vIFvPYHT7fO5-J4MIA)

Comment: That's genius! Thank you :)